# integrate linux partition types in windows explorer

Tags: windows, linux, windows-explorer, partitioning

is there any possible way to mount and use a linux partition like ext3 or ext4 in windows and manipulate them just like ntfs volumes? i mean like some program you intall and then you just assign drive letters to your linux partition?

Comment: http://www.google.com/search?q=ext3+windows+driver

Answer (score 1):

What you're talking about are [IFS drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installable_File_System).

There are several ones available for RW on ext2 and other read only for other file systems, see e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installable_File_System#External_links).

Answer (score 0):

There are some [IFS drivers](http://www.fs-driver.org/) for windows.